# How can I get MINIO access and secret key?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, storage, minio

I'm new to minio and I want to use it in a Django app, I read the documentation of [minio python library](https://pypi.org/project/django-minio-backend/) and there is fields for MINIO_ENDPOINT, MINIO_ACCESS_KEY, MINIO_SECRET_KEY. I read the [Quickstart documentation of minio](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-quickstart-guide) but I didn't figure out how to find these parameters.

Comment: minio defaults to minioadmin and minioadmin as the access key and secret key respectively. When you login change those.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you use docker:

```
environment:
            MINIO_ROOT_USER: ${MINIO_ROOT_USER}
            MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

---

Note that these two equivalent variables are now deprecated:

`MINIO_ACCESS_KEY[=MINIO_ROOT_USER]`

`MINIO_SECRET_KEY[=MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD]`

Comment: This naming convention took me an two hours to figure out.

Answer (score 14):

Go to your minio console and find Users page. You can create a new user and set it  MINIO_ACCESS_KEY and MINIO_SECRET_KEY or can view user credentials.

Comment: Note that your `policy` must allow for credentials reset, the default policy [`consoleAdmin`](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/security/minio-identity-management/policy-based-access-control.html#userpolicy.consoleAdmin) allows for that.

Comment: These variables are deprecated: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/identity-access-management/minio-user-management.html. @zemil 's answer shows the current variables. Also, if not set, it defaults to `minioadmin` value which is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

AccessKey is similar to username and should be minimum of 5 characters. SecretKey is similar to password, it should be randomly generated and kept secure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Its called Service Accounts, Go to Users menu, then Service Accounts sub menu.
create a new MINIO_ACCESS_KEY, MINIO_SECRET_KEY

Answer (score 1):

Please follow path:

1. Login to Minio
2. Access Keys
3. **Create Access Key**

At this location you will see the access key and secret key.

If you want to create new, click on **Create** button.

[image: Create access key]

Answer (score 0):

From the cluster

```
kubectl get secrets
NAME                              TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-hxzsv               kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      5h34m
minio-sa-token-nxdpt              kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      14m
mino-test-minio                   Opaque                                2      14m
my-s3-keys                        Opaque                                2      3h33m
mypostgres-secret                 Opaque                                2      5h20m
sh.helm.release.v1.mino-test.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      14m
alex@pop-os:~/coding/preso_hive$ kubectl get secret mino-test-minio -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  rootPassword: bWluaW8xMjM=
  rootUser: bWluaW8=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: mino-test
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-14T10:15:14Z"
  labels:
    app: minio
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: minio-4.0.2
    heritage: Helm
    release: mino-test
  name: mino-test-minio
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "58285"
  uid: c23ce2d4-657e-4feb-adea-df83bba489c5
type: Opaque
```

Note the rootUser and rootPassword from the secret and you can use base64 to decode

```
$ echo bWluaW8= | base64 --decode
minioalex

$ echo bWluaW8xMjM= | base64 --decode
minio123
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the ***Milvus database*** and looking for Milvus MinIO "Access Key" and "Secret Key" to log in to *http://IP_Address:9000* below are the default details:

```
Access Key: minioadmin
Secret Key: minioadmin
```